# Java8 и выше. Как правильно настроить память для JVM?

Tags: java, память, jvm

Есть java приложение активно использующее память за пределами кучи (jvm heap). В основном это jni вызовы и buffered объекты, т.е которые используются в NIO/2. 4ГБ выделенные jvm практически не используются (не считая памяти под статические константы размером 1ГБ). Как правильно настроить jvm для объектов не хранящихся в куче?

Comment: А зачем вы выделяете 4Гб, если они не используются? Поставьте меньше

Comment: Это не важный параметр. Важна оптимизация  работы с памятью за пределами кучи

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Все зависит от того как именно объекты выделяются. В общем случае JVM ни как не контролирует выделение памяти внутри нативных методов.

Для памяти выделенной под NIO буфера можно попробовать настроить `-XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=` или `-XX:MaxDirectMemorySize`.

Comment: Отлично. Спасибо. Судя по документации By default, the JVM does not set a limit on how much memory is reserved for Direct Byte Buffers. A soft limit of 64 MB is set, which the JVM automatically expands in 32 MB chunks, as required.